# How to Export Export ERD to JSON

Tags: json, entity-relationship

I have tried LucidChart, Draw.io, Gliffy, Visio, Visual Paradigm among others. I have created an ERD diagram and I want to export it to json format. Is there any way or free software to do this?

JSON to ERD is easy to find but ERD to JSON or Create SQL DDL to JSON is apparently not a common use case. I did find an open source [npm library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sql-ddl-to-json-schema) which is not well maintained.

Any software recommendations?